# Quick Union Algorithm in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, union

This is a code in the course Algorithms by Stanford that uses Quick Union to solve dynamic connectivity.

```
public class QuickUnionUF {
    private int[] id;

    // Set id of each object to itself
    public QuickUnionUF(int N) {
        id = new int[N];
        for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) id[i]  i;
    }

    private int root(int i) {
        while(i != id[i]) i = id[i];
        return i;
    }

    public boolean connected(int p, int q) {
        return root(p) == root(q);
    }

    public void union(int p, int q) {
        int i = root(p);
        int j = root(q);
        id[i] = j;
    }
}
```

I couldn't comprehend *how the root method works*. Can someone please explain it to me in a step-by-step manner?

Comment: `I couldn't comprehend how the root method works.`  I'm guessing it is simply a convention that the id of the root is itself.  So if the 0th element has a value of 0, then that's the root.

Comment: The id array values point to parent nodes. A root node will point to itself. So, for example, if you want to find the root of 7, you'll check id[7]. If it is a root node, the value will be 7. Otherwise, the value will be another integer which represents the parent node. You continue this until you find a parent node that equals itself, indicating that it is the root. I think your best best is to rewatch the quick union lecture and possibly step through the algorithm in a debugger with some sample data.

Comment: Is this a [disjoint set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure)?

Comment: I think this is the full source of this: https://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/15uf/QuickUnionUF.java.html

Answer (score 1):

The `id` field is a mapping: It maps any element to the element that is closer to the root than it. So, if '8' was unioned to '6', and '6' is unioned to '4', and 4 is the root, than `id[8]` will be either 6 or 4.

The `union(p, q)` method will first find the root of elem p, then the root of elem q (how? Let's just go with the flow and say that it does, let's worry about how the `root(p)` function works later).

It will then update the `id` table: the 'pointing at the road to the root' value for the root of elem p is set to the root of elem q. In other words, what used to be p's root is now no longer a root.

That's all there is to it, now it is easy to understand how that `root(p)` function works: It follows the `id` table and continues to do so, until it finds a node whose signpost that points at the road to the root, is pointing at itself: That is a property that roots have, so that value is returned.

Note that initialize, all elements start out as their own root (the `id` table is initialized so that e.g. `id[8] = 8`, `id[2] = 2`, etcetera. Calls to the `union` method will change the id table. `union(8, 2)` would then have `id[2] = 2` (q's root is unchanged, and initially, all elements are their own root, so root-of-2 is still just 2), but `id[8] = 2` now. If you then change 2's root, say, `union(2,1)`, then `id[8] = 2` remains unchanged, but `id[2] = 1`. 8 goes to 2, but you just said to the system that the road from 2 to the root is towards 1. So, the root of 8, is now 1. The `root` method will tell you this, but takes 2 steps: First it 'walks' to 2, then it 'walks' to 1, then it notices the next road to take leads to itself, so it returns.

Comment: If `id[i]  i` in the constructor is supposed to be `id[i] = i` wouldn't the `root()` get into an endless loop? Isn't some kind of initialization other than what is part of the code sample needed? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Erk I don't think so: Initially, `id[i] = i` is true for all nodes, which means the `root()` method will always loop zero times and return i immediately (`while (id[i] != i)` is false immediately). Once you use `union` a few times, that while loop goes a few times, but will end at some point. You can make it endless loop if you union 2 to 3, and then 3 to 2. Presumably, you're not supposed to do that (APIs failing their preconditions by endless looping aren't particularly nicely designed, of course. But, 'make this code nicer' wasn't the question).

Comment: harumpf! It's true. I'm asleep. `i` and `id[i]` is the same so `i != id[i]` is always false. Quack!

Comment: Yes, the `root()`-method is pretty unusable without calls to `union()`... I think that's what threw me off...